# win10 UWA app: Using winsock2, ws2bth.h ignored by compiler: BTHPROTO_RFCOMM not found

Tags: c++, bluetooth, windows-10-universal, winsock2

I try to create a Bluetooth connection between my PC and a target device using winsock2 API. I created a new Universal Windows App(C++) with VS 2015 and started to implement code I already used before with a win32 application and worked just fine into the MainPage.xaml.cpp.

I got the error: The identifier BTHPROTO_RFCOMM and SOCKADDR_BTH is not defined. They are both defined inside ws2bth.h and included in my code.

I can't find any reason why my code doesn't work have not found anything about ws2bth.h not working with Univeral Windows App.

Hope you can help me out here.

-Christian

Edit: I can actually jump to the definition with a right click on BTHPROTO_RFCOMM out of my MainPage.xaml.cpp, but the error remains.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 1

#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

SOCKET clientSocket;

using namespace MoodlightControl;

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;


MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

int startWinsock() {
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;

    // Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h 
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

    if (err != 0) 
        return 0;



    // Check, if Winsock2.2.dll supported                                       
    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2) {
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    else
        return 1;
}

int connect() {
    clientSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);

    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return 1;

    SOCKADDR_BTH bth_addr;

    bth_addr.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    bth_addr.btAddr = 0x98D331FD02D9;
    bth_addr.port = 1;

    if (connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &bth_addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        return 1;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check how your compiler's `ws2bth.h` file wraps its content in `#ifdef`s, and then make sure your project is configured accordingly.  In my compiler, `ws2bth.h` wraps its content with an `#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WINXPSP2)` statement, meaning the Bluetooth definitions are not available if the project is not configured to support XP SP2 and later. See [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx).

Comment: I tried adding a `#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_WIN10`. I get the following warning: `Warning C4005 "NTDDI_VERSION": Makro redefinition.` 
I also checked the properties manager, and my target platform version is defined as windows 10. I still get the error though

Comment: Did you ever fix the issue? I'm getting the same error...